# Fitnesse reads fixture class as method, gives 'missing method' exception

Tags: maven, classpath, fixtures, fitnesse

I have developed a maven project using DoFixture.

My JAVA code looks somewhat like this:

Package A

Class P extends DoFixture

Method X

---

Package A

Class Q extends DoFixture

```
 Method X

 Method Y
```

---

When I make a Fitnesse table for this, like,

! |A.Q|

| X |

| Y |

On running it, Fitnesse returns this exception-> method missing : AdotQ in class A.Q, but when I run,

! |A.P|

| X |

it runs fine.

Not able to understand why Fitnesse is reading AdotQ as a method when it is a class in my code.Please note, I have compiled the code using mvn install.

Comment: Can you post exception stack trace ?

Comment: I resolved the issue. Actually I wasn't importing fixture classes in my fitnesse suite. Thanks all for taking a look.